# File uploaded with <no name> using Set-AzStorageBlobContent

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload file from my local machine to azure blob using Powershell.

**Code**

```
$date = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy"
$Ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName abc -StorageAccountKey 'xxxxxx=='
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container jmeter -Blob "Result/Load1/$date/" -File "C:\Result.jtl" -Context $Ctx -Force
```

The hierarchy created successfully inside the container jmeter

e.g : Result/Load1/13-03-2020

But file uploaded with no name

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `-Blob "Result/Load1/$date/filename.jtl"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, it should be `-Blob "Load1/$date/Result.jtl"`.

```
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container test1 -Blob "Load1/$date/Result.jtl" -File "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\Result.jtl" -Context $Ctx -Force
```

[image]

[image]